# Storing actual repeating date's without the year part

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model

Using the Entity Framework data access model, I am attempting to store Clubs including their meeting day/time information. Instead of using a free text field for the user to write something on the lines of "We meet on a Wednesday 5-6 and Thursday 7-8" I instead wish to store the meeting day and times in a more meaningful format.

I have a Club model something along the lines of:

```
public class Club
    {
            public bool VisuallyImpairedWelcome { get; set; }           
            public string Explanation { get; set; }    
            public List<CalendarEntry> MeetingDays { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    }
```

CalendarEntry model looks like:

```
public class CalendarEntry
    {
        public int CalendarEntryId { get; set; }
        public int ClubId { get; set; }

        public Days Day { get; set; }
        public DateTime From { get; set; }
        public DateTime To { get; set; }

        public Intervals Interval { get; set; }
        public List<ExceptionDays> ExceptionDays { get; set; }
        public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem im having is with the `List<ExceptionDays>`, my thinking here would be the user could set up their regular meeting days i.e:

```
Monday 17:00 - 18:30
Wednesday 17:30 - 18:30

Occurrence: Every Week

Except Yearly: 25th December 26th December
```

Something along these lines, the problem is I have no idea how I should construct my `ExceptionDays` class, something along the lines of (pseudo:)

```
public class ExceptionDays
{
    int Day { get; set; }
    int Month { get; set; }
}
```

But obviously the Day/Month combination must be possible, and the date is to be excluded as this will be a re-occurring date.

Firstly am I taking the right approach here, if so how can I construct a water tight ExceptionDays class?

Comment: How would you handle "except Easter day" with this model? There's really no way of telling whether something is "water tight" without knowing every possible thing you want to represent.

Comment: Or maybe even "except first monday after full moon"...

Comment: I have a string for that named AdditionalInfo, I imagined here would go All bank holidays, Christmas Day, Boxing Day etc

Comment: @ jon-skeet I understand this is very difficult to model as there are almost infinite possibilities, however im trying to achieve some accurate way of storing the meeting day info as realistically as possible, can anyone offer an alternative approach or shall I just make the MeetingDays field free text and be done with it?

Comment: Simplest way is just to store a Date, with maybe a text field for a reason ('Christmas' or 'Full Moon' etc).

Comment: But then this date will have a year and will therefore become out of date next year, unless I create some sort of maintenance job to +1 to the year every interval.